# difference between go for a drink, go for drink and go for drinks

Tags: difference

When you suggest going to drink an alcoholic beverage, you may say:

> 1. Let's go for a drink.
> 2. Let's go for drink.
> 3. Let's go for drinks.

I searched for [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=go%20for%20a%20drink%2Cgo%20for%20drink%2C%20go%20for%20drinks&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20a%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20drinks%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20a%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20for%20drinks%3B%2Cc0) for the usages:

[image]

All of the three forms are used while 'go for a drink' is the preferred choice. Except for the frequency of usage, are there any differences in the meanings?

---

I thought of 'go to drink' also:

[image]

The 'go to drink' is less frequent than 'go for a drink' but more frequent than the others.

Comment: Some [more examples](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+for+a+drink%2Cgo+for+drinks%2Cgo+out+for+drinks%2Cgo+drinking%2Cgo+out+drinking%2Cget+drinks%2Cget+some+drinks&year_start=1900&year_end=2019). Also [this comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?&content=go+for+a+drink%2Cget+drinks%2C+get+a+drink&year_start=1900&year_end=2019).

Comment: @epl Thanks!! So 'get a drink' is even better actually.

Comment: Yes, but use it quickly... Since 2017 it has been going down!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. (1) is idiomatic, and roughly means "Let's go to a bar/pub/etc. and socialize for a little while." While alcohol will be served, it's not really the point of the exercise. Socially, this is equivalent to having lunch with someone, but with alcohol instead of food.
2. You cannot say (2), because the singular "drink" requires a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner). It is grammatically incorrect without "a" or another word to introduce it.
3. (3) implies going to the pub or bar (like (1)), but further connotes that you will be staying there for much of the evening. It's a longer time period than (1), though exactly how much longer will depend greatly on group dynamics and other factors.

Comment: Except "drink" can be non-count, and have a zero determiner. So I agree with 1 and 3, but I think 2 could be reworked.

Comment: It may be wise to avoid strong claims about social implications, as appear in some of these explanations. "Go for a drink" may express starkly different intention in a social context, compared to some mention of lunch not accompanied by any explicit reference to alcoholic beverages.

Comment: @epl: Re "incorrect" - This isn't EL&U. I'm trying to provide a useful resource for people who are learning English as a second language. A certain level of linguistic prescriptivism is useful in that context, although it's certainly possible to get carried away with it. I don't think that has happened in this case.

Comment: @epl: As a rule of thumb, singulars do require determiners, at least in simple present indicative as OP is using. I did not want to add a whole laundry list of qualifications, because the Wikipedia article already gives those anyway for people who care to click through, and it would be very confusing to provide a comprehensive explanation of exactly when and where determiners are required in English (it's a complicated subject) in response to a simple "Is X grammatical?" question.

Comment: @epl: Those examples are (1) referring to abstract concepts, not specific identifiable items, and (2) idiomatic expressions (i.e. the construction is not [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics))).

Comment: Just to clarify my comment.  I agree that "go for drink" is wrong (in nearly every conceivable context)  But the explanation you give isn't quite right.  The assertion "singulars do require determiners" is way off!  Singular non-count nouns can have the zero article.  And drink can be non-count.  But the non-count meaning (alcohol consumption in general) doesn't fit the context.   You could, I suppose say "I will work for drink" (get paid in alcohol) but you wouldn't say "go for drink".  You just need to explain that, hopefully better than I just did.

Comment: @JamesK: This is *exactly* the lengthy, off-topic explanation that I did not want to bother the OP with. I linked to the article so they could read more detail *if they wanted it.* If you have a better link, I can switch it, but I am not going to triple the length of my answer to explain an incredibly nitpicky point that does not help to illuminate OP's question in the slightest.

Comment: No one is suggesting that a complicated explanation is required. Your language literally qualifies the phrase as "__grammatically__ incorrect", and references a source that is both arcane and off topic. Simply indicating that the phrase is not in active vernacular use resolves the question unambiguously and prevents the eventuality that someone might comb a a lengthy list for some phantom rule.

Comment: (To be clear, the rules in the article are *arcane*, not the source itself, Wikipedia.)

Comment: @epl: I am not willing to remove it. When I read English text written by non-native speakers (particularly from eastern Asia), incorrect omission of a determiner is one of the most frequent errors I observe. It is important to educate them on this point.